# How to prevent ng-idle from watching on login page in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented ng-idle watch and Keep-alive in my angular client which monitors the idle activity of logged in users. My issue is that the ng-idle is also working on the login page when the system starts, which looks like loop of some sort.

The implementation is in my app.component.ts. The code in my root app.component.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SessionTimeoutService } from './compas/services/session.service';
import { AuthService } from './compas/services/auth.service';
import { MySharedService } from './compas/services/sharedService';
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Idle, EventTargetInterruptSource } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { MessagingService } from './compas/services/messaging.service';
import { Keepalive } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';
import { ProgressBarModalComponent } from './progressbar-modal.component';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
idleState = 'NOT_STARTED';
timedOut = false;
lastPing?: Date = null;
progressBarPopup: NgbModalRef;
currentPath: String;

constructor(private sessionTimeoutService: SessionTimeoutService, private messagingService: MessagingService,
  private authService: AuthService, private element: ElementRef, private idle: Idle, private keepalive: Keepalive,
   private ngbModal: NgbModal, private router: Router, private globalService: MySharedService) {


  // // sets an idle timeout of 15 minutes.
   idle.setIdle(180);
  // // sets a timeout period of 5 minutes.
   idle.setTimeout(300);
  // sets the interrupts like Keydown, scroll, mouse wheel, mouse down, and etc
  idle.setInterrupts([
    new EventTargetInterruptSource(
      this.element.nativeElement, 'keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown touchstart touchmove scroll')]);

  idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => {
    this.idleState = 'NO_LONGER_IDLE';
  });

  idle.onTimeout.subscribe(() => {
    this.idleState = 'TIMED_OUT';
    this.timedOut = true;
    this.closeProgressForm();
  });

  idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => {
    this.idleState = 'IDLE_START', this.openProgressForm(1);
  });

  idle.onTimeoutWarning.subscribe((countdown: any) => {
    this.idleState = 'IDLE_TIME_IN_PROGRESS';
    this.progressBarPopup.componentInstance.count = (Math.floor((countdown - 1) / 60) + 1);
    this.progressBarPopup.componentInstance.progressCount = this.reverseNumber(countdown);
    this.progressBarPopup.componentInstance.countMinutes = (Math.floor(countdown / 60));
    this.progressBarPopup.componentInstance.countSeconds = countdown % 60;
  });

  // sets the ping interval to 15 seconds
  keepalive.interval(15);
  /**
   *  // Keepalive can ping request to an HTTP location to keep server session alive
   * keepalive.request('<String URL>' or HTTP Request);
   * // Keepalive ping response can be read using below option
   * keepalive.onPing.subscribe(response => {
   * // Redirect user to logout screen stating session is timeout out if if response.status != 200
   * });
   */

   this.reset();
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:use-life-cycle-interface
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.resetTimeOut();
  this.logout();
}

reverseNumber(countdown: number) {
  return (300 - (countdown - 1));
}

reset() {
  this.idle.watch();
  this.idleState = 'Started.';
  this.timedOut = false;
}

openProgressForm(count: number) {
  this.progressBarPopup = this.ngbModal.open(ProgressBarModalComponent, {
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  });
  this.progressBarPopup.componentInstance.count = count;
  this.progressBarPopup.result.then((result: any) => {
    if (result !== '' && 'logout' === result) {
      this.logout();
    } else {
      this.reset();
    }
  });
}

logout() {
  // localStorage.removeItem('session');
  this.authService.logout(this.globalService.username).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('User logged out');
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('error logging out');
  });
  this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
  this.globalService.setAuth(false);
  localStorage.removeItem('otc');
  this.resetTimeOut();
}

closeProgressForm() {
  this.progressBarPopup.close();
  this.authService.logout(this.globalService.username).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('User logged out');
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('error logging out');
  });
  this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
}

resetTimeOut() {
  this.idle.stop();
  this.idle.onIdleStart.unsubscribe();
  this.idle.onTimeoutWarning.unsubscribe();
  this.idle.onIdleEnd.unsubscribe();
}

// tslint:disable-next-line:use-life-cycle-interface
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

I expect the login page to be free of the idle watch implementation since it is the entry  point of the system. Where do I need to rectify in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Before initializing ng-idle, check if the user is authenticated and if not authenticated, just keep an observable on authentication and once authenticated, initialize the same..

Comment: I have a login component that handles the authentication. Do I need to re-use the same logic?